# Cookies not set from AJAX Angular/Laravel call

Tags: angularjs, ajax, laravel

I have a Angular and Laravel application. The Laravel server handles all API requests from the frontend Angular client. When the client makes a call to the server, the cookies in the API response are not set on the client browser. The response in the header looks correct:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, Content-Type, X-XSRF-TOKEN, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:close
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Sun, 26 Jun 2016 02:06:01 GMT
Host:localhost:8000
Set-Cookie:XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImJzK3VTcTVBb3l5dTdGTXBweWpGTEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiXC9ERE1Rb3E5U2NaRytKcytFOU8yK2lpN1BVMVBoajFjUUtMdTdPeXRIT0krbUJTNEtwOWM4NU0zTDJxckN2QXlFREV5SVJiY2tjWGNJQUxmR1wvYTh5dz09IiwibWFjIjoiZWMyYWEyYWNkYzMzYzBmZDcyNzZhYWU5ZjFiNDJmNDQxNjVkNDhiYzI0Yjc2ZDU3MTU2MjFhMjE0NjZmMzU0MiJ9; expires=Sun, 26-Jun-2016 04:06:01 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
Set-Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImFSN0pLSkJXbkU0dXoxaTdhN1p4SUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiV1wvNGFrTnlqT0RvU0U4T0owMll5Q0s5UnVDSmNzeHF3bmltdjJHZ081emxDcVwveFMwWXhFZFlLaWhxT1J2c1ExOE1TVFNKVk9tdmZzc0hTSDFDMEFEdz09IiwibWFjIjoiNWE3MDE2ZjNiZjM1M2UwYjI2ODQ3MmE2MGFjZjU4NGNmZjZlOWYyN2QwNTk0MmJjYmM1NjE0NjA1YmJhODNjNyJ9; expires=Sun, 26-Jun-2016 04:06:01 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.35
```

The `XSRF-TOKEN` and `laravel_session` tokens are not set.  Do I need to do anything specifically on the Angular side to save the cookies or should the cookies just set automatically?

Comment: How do you determine they aren't set? Are you using `withCredentials` in requests?

Comment: Right on, it turns out that I wasn't setting withCredentials.

Comment: Yeah....allows cross domain cookie handling that way

Answer (score 0):

If you are building an API with Laravel, make sure to use the `api` middleware instead of the `web` middleware which is defined in the `RouteServicePovicer.php` class by default. You don't need cookies or CSRF token protection for APIs, you have token authentication for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks I will look into this.